# How do I create a App shell that is cached for a Progressive Web app in a React App?

Tags: user-interface, reactjs, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

Currently, I use webpack to build a single JS file which represents my app. How do I split my React app UI shell from rest of the app logic, so that I can have the service Worker cache it?

My webpackpack config file looks like this, that generates a single index_bundle.js file(no css file):

```
import webpack from 'webpack'
import path from 'path'
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin'
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer'

const LAUNCH_COMMAND = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event

const isProduction = LAUNCH_COMMAND === 'production'
process.env.BABEL_ENV = LAUNCH_COMMAND

const PATHS = {
  root: path.join(__dirname),
  app: path.join(__dirname, 'app'),
  build: path.join(__dirname, 'dist')
}

const HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: PATHS.app + '/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
})

const productionPlugin = new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env': {
    NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
  }
})

const productionPlugin2 = new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
  compressor: {
    warnings: false
  }
})

const base = {
  entry: [
    'babel-polyfill',
    PATHS.app
  ],
  output: {
    path: PATHS.build,
    filename: 'index_bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader'},
      {test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style!css?sourceMap&modules&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]&importLoader=1!postcss'}
    ]
  },
  postcss: [ autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 versions'] }) ],
  resolve: {
    root: path.resolve('./app')
  }
}

const developmentConfig = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: PATHS.build,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true,
    inline: true,
    progress: true
  },
  plugins: [HTMLWebpackPluginConfig, new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()]
}

const productionConfig = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  plugins: [HTMLWebpackPluginConfig, productionPlugin, productionPlugin2]
}

export default Object.assign({}, base, isProduction === true ? productionConfig : developmentConfig)
```

Answer (score 3):

My "[Instant Loading with Service Workers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jCKZDTtUA2A)" talk from the Chrome Dev Summit 2015 covers creating a PWA using the App Shell + dynamic model, powered by React.

The code sample for it is part of the `sw-precache` library's repo: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache/tree/master/app-shell-demo

(It's not necessarily the most idiomatic React code in the world, but the general concepts, especially when it comes to the service worker implementation, should hold.)

Comment: i'm using webpack for build process and currently just generating only one bundle.js file, even after watching your video and looking through the github repo I 'm unclear as how to generate a separate app shell file that i can cache with sw-precache

Comment: hey @jasan , how did you end up doing this?

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/squoosh may help also